# Downgrade Ubuntu (18.04 to 16.04) or make php on apach2 work

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, lamp

I am new on this forum so sorry if my topic is not on the rules or not at the good place, it's my first post.
I have a little problem, I actualy work on a project for an intership and have a server on ubuntu. I want to make my server using https instead of http. I see on internet than a version of ubuntu 16.04 is recommanded (I was on Ubuntu 14.04 at this moment). I updated my ubuntu with this tutorial :
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-lts
The problem is this tutorial don't install me Ubuntu 16.04 but Ubuntu 18.04. When i try go on my phpmyadmin, it don't interpret the php code and show me a page with the php script (I already try to uninstall and re-install Apache2, MySql, php7.2 and phpmyadmin). After some hours of research on internet i don't see where my configuraton of LAMP have a trouble so i've decided to downgrade my Ubuntu and re-install my LAMP server. Apparently it's impossible to downgrade Ubuntu without unistall and re-install it. So i don't know how to do that because the host of my server is in France and I'am on Japan for my internship. I actually work on my project with a ssh connection so can I do it by ssh ? 
If it is not possible can you help me to find where my configuration of LAMP have a trouble ? 
Thanks a lot for your help and sorry for my horrible inglish and this lllooonnnggg text.

Comment: I would recommend you to just install Ubuntu from scratch. Once you've started upgrading etc and something goes wrong, you will most likely end up with a wonky install which takes a lot of time and effort to sort out (if you even can).

Comment: You can also try asking here for further information. https://askubuntu.com/ Just like Magnus has said I would also recommend a fresh install.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response :) But i don't know if i can uninstall and install an old version of Ubuntu in distant server with ssh .

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should better understand an error why your server doesn't interpret your PHP code. It's less problem than reinstall full system at all.

Have you checked apache logs? Have you checked if PHP installed OK?

My advice is to install panel, for example, [free Vesta](https://vestacp.com/install/) and panel install all services for you (instead of LAMPP). IMHO, it's better than LAMP for remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Rufus tool to create a bootableUSB flash drive for Ubuntu 16.4 so that I can downgrade my Ubuntu from 18.4 to 16.4. See [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5ZTGIrjBsU).

By following the new install instructions for 16.4, it worked. In terms of options, I checked the following:

1. Since I didn't want to keep 18.4, I erased it by checking the box for formatting the / partition.
2. To keep my data files intact, I unchecked the box for formatting the /home partition.

Below is the output of the "df /dev/sda* -h" command for my 80G HDD after downgrade:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.3G     0  1.3G   0% /dev
udev            1.3G     0  1.3G   0% /dev
/dev/sda2        37G  4.2G   31G  12% /home
/dev/sda5       3.7G   73M  3.4G   3% /boot
/dev/sda6        30G  4.1G   24G  15% /
udev            1.3G     0  1.3G   0% /dev
```

which has allocated 32G for /, 4G for /boot, 4G for /swap and 40G for /home.

To verify, I issued
"cat /etc/lsb-release" and got:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS"
```

Answer (score -2):

you want to downgrade the Ubuntu 18 to Ubuntu 16, kindly follow the procedures below.

1. insert Ubuntu 16 CD In a system, choose boot from CD and choose install Ubuntu 16.
2. while installing  automatically it comes like uninstall the Ubuntu 18 and reinstall it again.select the option and continue.(follow the same procedure like ubuntu 18)
3. same partition it will take it will not erase any data and will downgrade to Ubuntu16.

   4. same it will applied or dual boot.